# How to not change value if an input is empty

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have written this code for a form I was working on.

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="labels">Doğum Günü:</label>
    <input method="POST"name="birtdate" class="form-control" {% if student.birtdate%} type="text"value="{{student.birtdate}}" onfocus="(this.type='date')"onblur="(this.type='text')" {%else %}type="date" {% endif %}>
</div>
```

It should show the initial value when blur and turn into a date field when focused. The problem is when I click on it and then click away it shows an empty value. I need to somehow check that and make it not change the value if the input is empty. How can I do that?

Comment: The 'POST' method should be set in form like < from method="POST" .....>

Comment: I think in your code `{% if student.birtdate%}` is a type error,, correct syntax will be `{% if student.birtdate %}` and your POST method should be like this `<form method="POST" ...>`

Comment: @Jisson in your comment the **from** should be **form**. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but if your input changes onblur then does it retain and translate the value from date to text. I think the value resets to default when you change the type. it would be better to write a function to parse the date to text and then set this.value to that instead of just simply using one line statements.

```
date = this.value
this.type = text
this.value = date.toString()
```